# Custom Asset Source Types - not possible

Tags: plugin-development, assets, s3, extends

I would love to extend Craft with a custom AssetSourceType. However it looks like components of type 'assetSource' are not extensible (enableForPlugins = false).

Is there a way to do this?
Or can I simply swap core services in the `common.php` without hacking the core?

My goal is to provide a 'S3CompatAssetSourceType' - the main difference to the S3AssetSourceType is the API endpoint.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Custom Asset sources are not possible in Craft 2 without some core hacking.

However totally doable in [Craft 3](https://craftcms.com/3) (even in the dev preview).  There is an example of how to pull it off [here](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/flysystem-google-cloud).

Comment: Besides changing enableForPlugins to true in common.php, what other core hacking would be necessary?

Comment: The reason I ask is because this didn't seem to do the trick for me...

Comment: Possible something has broken or changed since we released the last dev preview.  Good news is, we hope to have a new one out soonish.